# Uncaught ReferenceError: getStr is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test addEventListener with a function as an argument to a closure function. if I call without addEventListener it gives me the value and using addEventListener give the error that getStr is not a function.
Any help please!

---

```
Name: <input type="text" id = "myText" value="" placeholder="String ..." />
<button type="submit">Submit Search</button>
<div id="od"></div>

var getStrVal = (function(strFunc) {
    console.log(strFunc);
    document.getElementById("od").innerHTML = strFunc;
})();

//get string value              
var strSol = function() {
    var searchStr = document.getElementById("myText").value;
}

addEventListener("click", getStrVal(strSol), false);
```

Comment: Its `getStrVal()` not `getStr()` and you are immediately invoking it.

Comment: Fixed it, but the error is the same. 'Uncaught TypeError: getStrVal is not a function'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working sample of what you are trying to achieve.
I have removed your immediately invoked `getStrVal` function which gave you `Uncaught TypeError: getStrVal is not a function`

```js
var getStrVal = function(strFunc) {
    document.getElementById("od").innerHTML = strFunc();
};

//get string value              
var strSol = function() {
    return document.getElementById("myText").value;
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  getStrVal(strSol);
};
```

```html
Name: <input type="text" id = "myText" value="" placeholder="String ..." />
<button id="btn" type="submit">Submit Search</button>
<div id="od"></div>
```

Comment: One more thing that, if I use the script in another .js file and call the function it gives error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null'. it seems to me that it is firing before getting value.

Comment: Now when I moved the <script> from header to body under HTML. then it worked.

Comment: How you do it to make the answer?

Comment: CodeLover, Can you please check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861503/wikipedia-viewer-script-not-printing-the-page