# Wikipedia Viewer Script not printing the page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print Wikipedia Page, but not getting any data. I used JSONP to retrieve the data. It seems that I am missing some links. I trying to print the clean page not in JSON.stringify format.

Please help.

```
<div id="myUrl"></div>
<div id="myCallback"></div>
<div id="myQuery"></div>
<div id="myPage"></div>    



var getJSON = function(k) {

    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&generator=search&gsrsearch=italy&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=extracts&exchars=200&exlimit=max&explaintext=true&exintro=true";

    document.getElementById("myUrl").innerHTML = url;

    var createCallback = function (k) {
        var i = 1;
        var callbackName;
        do {
            callbackName = 'callback' + i;
            i = i + 1;
        } while (window[callbackName])
        window[callbackName] = k;
        return callbackName;
    }
    document.getElementById("myCallback").innerHTML = createCallback();

    return function (k) {
    //document.getElementById("myQuery").innerHTML = k + "<br><br>";

        callback = createCallback(k);
        url = url + "&callback=" + callback;
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.src = url;
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        head.appendChild(script);
   };   
}

    var getCallback = function(data) {
        document.getElementById("myPage").innerHTML = data.query;
    }

    getJSON(getCallback);
```

Comment: Hello, is Anyone there?

Comment: This is pretty messed up. Can you post a snippet demonstration this?